# Could not access my wordpress admin

Tags: php, wordpress, admin

Yesterday I updated my blog wordpress version to the latest one and it updated successfully.
I worked on [my site](http://www.imrantariq.com/blog) after updation and there was no problem.Today when I tried to access my dashboard I found a blank white page. I am little bit worried about hacking my blog.
What could be the problem? Why I could not access my blog admin? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If it's a blank page, it sounds like a parse error. Do you have [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) turned on? IE, `error_reporting(E_ALL);`.

Comment: I don't know about parse error. I am a novice wordpress admin.

Comment: I'd try the WordPress forums, or maybe Super User (Stack Exchange site). This isn't really the kind of question that's resolved here.

Comment: Wanted to recommend http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ since this is less a php/wordpress coding question. But you seem to already know about it. Still, it might need some more details (WP version, etc.), and enabling `error_reporting` is the way to go.

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks all. Where should I set error_reporting(E_ALL);. In wp-admin index.php page?

Comment: `wp-config.php` or `index.php` in root directory.

Comment: btw, did you disabled all plugins *before* upgrade, right?

Comment: No. i did not disable them. Can it cause any problem?

Comment: I am trying to make error_reporting on. But could not do so. I added  ini_set('display_errors',1); 
 error_reporting(E_ALL); in index.php and admin.php page in admin-content. It did not work. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like a PHP error, which is not being displayed because of the error_reporting settings. If you have access to your error logs you might be able to work out what the problem is, but given that you're a novice I would recommend asking your hosting provider to look into it for you.

Comment: How to access error logs. Where are they?

Comment: I am on a live server. I only have access to code and database.

Comment: If you're on a shared hosting platform, your logs may be accessible through cPanel or Plesk, or whatever you use. I strongly recommend contacting your hosting provider. With no specific errors there's little anyone here can do to help you.